# IEの開発ツール、コンソールにコマンド入力しても結果を表示しないＷｅｂページがある

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptの参考書で、実習用のHTML（Webページ）をダウンロードしました。

このWebページを開発ツール（IE）で開き、下部コマンド枠にJavaScriptを入力して実行してみる、という課題があり早速挑戦したところ、いきなり参考書と異なる結果を招いてしまいました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
添付のとおりですが、自分のIEの開発ツールでは結果を表示しませんでした。参考書やFireFoxで同じことを試すと結果を表示するのに。また一般のWebページで開発ツールからコマンド入力するとしっかり結果を表示します。

これはブラウザの性質ということで、納得すべきことでしょうか？
IEの開発ツールで、コンソールにコマンド入力しても　結果を表示しないケースは何が問題なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

セキュリティ上の理由により、デフォルトではローカルに保存されたアクティブコンテンツ(JavaScript等のプログラムの様に振る舞うもの)は動作が許可されていないので、こちらが原因ではないでしょうか。

リスクを十分に理解した上で、IEの詳細設定から「マイコンピュータのファイルでのアクティブコンテンツの実行を許可する」を有効にすれば実行できるようになると思います。
(デバッグが終わったら元に戻すことをお勧めします)

参考：
[アクティブコンテンツのローカル表示制限を解除する](http://biw.xii.jp/ie/IEsecurity01.htm)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。まさに仰られるとおりでした。
参考書片手に早々に躓き、気がめいっていたので本当に助かりました